# Is there a way to combine annotations and filtered aggregations in Django Querysets?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a complex query that, although it is easily done in python code, I'm trying to do through Django Querysets.

Using the example models from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations, what I'm trying to do is to annotate each Publisher with the average of the total sales per author. However, the total sales per author should only include books from a given date range.

Is there any way to do this in one query? Of course, doing two separate queries and joining the results using pure Python would work. However, in my specific use case, there is a large amount of overhead for each database connection/disconnection, so it would be preferable to combine them into one query. Additionally, the real data set is quite large, so having the aggregation done server-side is vital.

Here is an example of the json output I would expect:

`{
  "publishers": [{
    "name": "testpublisher",
    "avg_recent_sales": "11.2"
  }, {
    "name": "anotherpublisher",
    "avg_recent_sales": "2.4"
  }]
}`

Where `avg_recent_sales` is the average amount of books each author sold through that publisher in the past 6 months.

Comment: Just filter first. `Book.objects.filter(publication_date__lt=last_date).annotate(...).aggregate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Django queryset is lazy. You can do filter or annotate as many times as you want until you iterate it (such as put it in "for" or convert it into a "list")

I've add "sold_amount" into Book model.

```py
books = Book.objects.filter(pubdate__range=(date1, date2))  # filter by given date range.
books = books.values('publisher__id', 'authors__id')  # create group by clause.
books = books.annotate(total_sale_per_author=Avg(F('sold_amount') * F('price')))  # add an annotation.

books = list(book)  # query will be occured here
```

Comment: Ah, but see, then you're annotating the Books. I need to annotate each publisher, which only seems doable through some form of nested annotation.

Comment: I wish to see a json of data you want from query.

Comment: Something along the lines of:

`{
  "publishers": [{
    "name": "testpublisher",
    "avg_recent_sales": "11.2"
  }, {
    "name": "anotherpublisher",
    "avg_recent_sales": "2.4"
  }]
}`



Where `avg_recent_sales` is the average amount of books each author sold through that publisher in the past 6 months.

Comment: you should also provide your model because the one you referenced has no data about the selling amount of each book through each publisher